# How do you create all possible combinations of size X, from multiple lists, pulling from each list in order

Tags: python, list

I have 4 lists and I want to create all possible combinations of exactly 18 values in these lists. I need to pull from each list in order though, so I can't use itertools.combinations. Also each element in the list can only be used once. So there can't be two 'QB1' values in each output.

I also need to set a rule where certain lists need at least X values used.

Min usage by list:

```
qb: 1
rb: 2
wr: 3
te: 1

qb = ['QB1', 'QB2', 'QB3']
rb = ['RB1', 'RB2', 'RB3', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB6', 'RB7', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB10']
wr = ['WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'WR4', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR7', 'WR8', 'WR9', 'WR10', 'WR11']
te = ['TE1', 'TE2', 'TE3', 'TE4', 'TE5']
```

Example Output:

```
['QB1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'RB3', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB6', 'RB7', 'RB8', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'TE2', 'TE3']
```

Example of an output that we don't want:

```
['QB5', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'RB3', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB6', 'RB7', 'RB8', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'TE2', 'TE3']
```

In the bad example, QB5 was used before QB1/QB2/QB3/QB4.
Each list needs to be used in order.

I tried using itertools.combinations, but that results in values at the end of the list being used in some combinations before the values at the beginning. Doing that many combinations would also break my computer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, try using the `{}` button in the editor to format variables and code better, otherwise good question

Comment: In your example, does the "min usage by list" mean that you want at least one element from `qb`, at least 2 from `rb`, at least 3 from `wr` and at least one from `te`? So the output should contain at least <so many> elements from <each list> but should have a total output length of 18? i.e. the remaining (18-1-2-3-1 = 11) items can come from any list(s)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes that's exactly right!

Comment: Super! Do you want to get any one valid output at random, or do you want to get all valid outputs?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I need all valid outputs. Hoping it's not too missive where it just breaks my computer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I think that I got the gist, something that does what you want, but with repetitions of items from the same list is:

```
import random

qb = ['QB1', 'QB2', 'QB3']
rb = ['RB1', 'RB2', 'RB3', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB6', 'RB7', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB10']
wr = ['WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'WR4', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR7', 'WR8', 'WR9', 'WR10', 'WR11']
te = ['TE1', 'TE2', 'TE3', 'TE4', 'TE5']

lists = [qb, rb, wr, te]
combs = []
i = 0
while True:
    combs.append(random.choice(lists[i]))
    if random.random() > 0.9:
        i += 1
    if i == len(lists) or len(combs) == 18:
        break
print(combs)
```

If repetitions from the same lists are to be avoided just add a check on the randomly chosen item if it has been chosen again.

Output:

```
['QB3', 'QB2', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'QB2', 'RB10', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB8', 'RB1', 'RB5', 'RB8', 'RB4', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB1', 'RB3', 'WR3']
```

Comment: Sorry if I was too vague. I need each list to be taken from in order, and there can't be duplicates. So with your output, QB3 was used before QB1, and there are dups. So in order for QB2 to appear in an output, QB1 had to be selected first. Same with QB3. You would need QB1 and then QB2 at some point before that. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
def binPack():

    inputs = [['QB1', 'QB2', 'QB3'],
              ['RB1', 'RB2', 'RB3', 'RB4', 'RB5', 'RB6', 'RB7', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB10'],
              ['WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'WR4', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR7', 'WR8', 'WR9', 'WR10', 'WR11'],
              ['TE1', 'TE2', 'TE3', 'TE4', 'TE5']
              ]

    constraints = [1,2,3,1]
    total = 18

    minChoices = [itertools.combinations(L,c) for L,c in zip(inputs, constraints)]  # the minimum required selection from each list
    for minChoice in itertools.product(*minChoices):  # for each combination of minimal required choices
        remainders = [set(L) for L in inputs]  # the remaining choices from each list. We'll remove what we've already chosen
        for r,remainder in enumerate(remainders):
            for c in minChoice[r]:
                remainder.remove(c)

        remainders = sum([list(r) for r in remainders], start=[])  # all possible remaining choices to add to the answer
        for c in itertools.combinations(remainders, total-len(minChoice)):
            yield tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(minChoice)) + c
```

Here's the first 10 outputs:

```
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR8')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR4')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR9')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR10')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'WR11')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'TE5')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'TE4')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'TE3')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR6', 'TE2')
('QB1', 'RB1', 'RB2', 'WR1', 'WR2', 'WR3', 'TE1', 'QB2', 'QB3', 'RB8', 'RB9', 'RB6', 'RB5', 'RB3', 'RB7', 'RB4', 'RB10', 'WR7', 'WR5', 'WR8', 'WR4')
```

Comment: This is VERY close to what I need! The only adjustment is that the lists need to be taken from in order. So with the first output you gave, WR5, WR6, WR7 and WR8 were used. But I need WR4 to be used before all of those. And with the 3rd output, WR9 was used, but WR8 wasn't. So that's an invalid output too. Does that make sense? Basically, the lists all need to be selected from in order.

Comment: @nzylak: in that case, you'll need to sort `remainders` to reflect this bias. This is best done just before the line that currently reads `remainders = sum(...)`. You could sort each remainder list by the position of the element in the input (since the input seems to capture the bias) or by the trailing integer value (eg: `3` for "QB3")