# What's the most efficient way to check if a value will be a duplicate when using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, set, append, permutation

I'm trying to get all unique permutations for the below list. Collecting all of them and then finding the uniques is impossible since it'll crash the computer (I need combinations of 18). To solve this I'm trying to check if a value is unique before adding it to the list or set. Just doing that for permutations of 6 or 7 has proven to take a long time though, so how I have it set up now just won't work for 18. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
pos = ['QB', 'QB', 'QB',
       'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB', 'RB',
       'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR', 'WR',
       'TE', 'TE', 'TE', 'TE', 'TE']

combos = set()

for combo in itertools.permutations(pos, 18):
    if combo not in combos:
        combos.add(combo)
```

The above takes about 40 seconds to run for permutations of size 6. No way it'll work for size 18.

Comment: `combos` is a set, so you don't need the `if` check at all; `set` will only add a unique value. The whole thing could reduce to `combos = set(itertools.permutations(pos, 18))` but that still may be too slow for you

Comment: What do you mean by unique permutations? Are you trying to find `combinations()`?

Comment: @RyanHaining `permutations` still *produces* all the duplicate permutations, even if `combos.add(...)` will silently discard them.

Comment: @chepner yeah I'm not saying it's _good_, I'm just saying it's better since OP seems to not know how set.add works.

Comment: What's special about 18? Do you really want permutations that, e.g, contain 3 QBs, 11 RBs, and 4 TEs, but no WRs?

Comment: And do you actually want *permutations*? For example, `("QB", "WR", "QB")` and `("QB", "QB", "WR")` would be two distinct permutations of size 3 of the same selection of two QBs and one WR.

Comment: @chepner yea it has to be 18. And no I do need min counts of certain ones (1 QB, 2 RB, 3 WR, 1 TE), but I figured I'd just eliminate the ones that don't meet that criteria after.

Comment: 18! = 6402373705728000 it is a huge number. Even if you do `for i in range(6402373705728000):
    lis.append(i)`  it will take years to finish

Comment: @chepner Yes I want permutations. I'm treating each value as a round. So the first set you listed would be: QB in round 1, WR in round 2, QB in round 3. Compared to the second you listed which is: QB in round 1, QB in round 2, WR in round 3.

Comment: @PolatkanPolat I could definitely be wrong, but I believe there are fewer combinations than that since there are only specific amounts of each string in pos.

Comment: Ok, there's no one simple algorithm for what you want.  And the total number of selections is probably still much bigger than you can manage. Even ignoring order, there are 136,125 ways to choose 1 QB, 2 RB, 3 WR, and 1 TE, and that's before considering the 1,352,078 ways to pad out each of *those* selections.

Comment: @RyanHaining I tried doing that way but it does produce dups for my purposes. It'll treat all 'RB' values as different, even though starting off 'RB', 'WR', 'RB' is always the same. No matter which value of 'RB' was selected. Does that make sense?

Comment: So are you really planning on iterating over 184,051,617,750 choices? You definitely aren't going to *store* that many in memory at once. (And remember, I'm still treating these as *sets*, not the distinct permutations whose elements are the same.)

Comment: @chepner Yea I mean I guess my question was is this even possible. I feel like I'm explaining it wrong, because I got sort of close using a different method and there were far fewer combinations than the 18! you'd think it is.

This was my first post about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102679/how-do-you-create-all-possible-combinations-of-size-x-from-multiple-lists-pull

Comment: 18! is 6 *quadrillion*. My estimate is an extremely loose lower bound, because I'm treating permutations of a set as an equivalent, and even that is probably intractable.

Comment: I have overcounted a bit: I pointed out that `(QB, WR, QB)` and `(QB, QB, WR)` are different, but ignored that, say, `(QB1, QB2, WR)` and `(QB2, QB1, WR)` are the same. (I've been thinking of the this as having a distinct set of quarterbacks available to choose from, not as just picking *a* quarterback first, another second: which two are picked "together" does not matter.)

Answer (score 2):

I found a lot better algorithm , but still not sure it is the best.
We can use tree structure , we can think all different items as different tree nodes. We will start with an empty root and add all different tree nodes if we have it, until it reaches desired length. In this case we have 4 different tree nodes  `("QB", "RB", "WR", "TE")`, so our tree will grow roughly `4**n`, we will store path information and if we reach desired length we will add the path.Here is my solution:

```
from time import time

# We will store all paths as a list in this global variable list
all_paths = []


class TreeNode:
    max_length_of_permutation = 6

    def __init__(self,remaining_tree_dict,length,path):
        self.remaining_tree_dict = remaining_tree_dict
        self.length = length # Lentgh of root to this tree
        self.path = path # Path of root to this tree
        self.create_childs() 

    def create_childs(self):
        # We check if we reached the max length
        if self.length < self.max_length_of_permutation:

            #We will create all possible child trees
            for tree in self.remaining_tree_dict:

                # We will copy because wo don't want to change original remaining_tree_dict
                new_remaining_tree_dict = self.remaining_tree_dict.copy()

                # We update new_remaining_tree_dict by subtracting the tree we will create
                new_remaining_tree_dict[tree] -= 1

                # If we don't have this tree in new_remaining_tree_dict anymore, we will delete
                if new_remaining_tree_dict[tree] == 0:
                    del new_remaining_tree_dict[tree]

                # We are creating new tree node with updated remaining trees, length and path, No need to assign
                TreeNode(new_remaining_tree_dict,self.length + 1,self.path + [tree])

        # if we reach to max_length we add path to our global path variable
        else:
            all_paths.append(self.path)







initial_remaining_trees = {
    'QB':3,
    'RB':11,
    'WR':11,
    'TE':5,
}

cur_time = time()

# We create root tree with initial values
root = TreeNode(remaining_tree_dict = initial_remaining_trees, length = 0, path = [])

print(time() - cur_time)
print(all_paths)
```

so if we set max_length_of_permutation = 6 it is really fast.I tried a little bit larger different lengths also mathematically calculated number of permutations here is the results:

```
# 11 -> 2853248     num, 3.5 sec
# 12 -> 10048638    num, 11 sec
# 13 -> 34615984    num, 40 sec
# 14 -> 116607556   num, 242 sec
# 15 -> 384175688   num, ?
# 16 -> 1238482830  num, ?
# 17 -> 3908904792  num, ?
# 18 -> 12083761976 num, ?
```

So we can estimate it will take hours to complete. And i also calculated that since number of permutations for 18 is 12083761976, in best algorithm let's say we calculate every permutation O(1) time , adding this permutations to store in a list will take roughly 10 minutes.So don't expect really fast algorithm

I hope this is helpful